# Cobordisms between spheres

Tags: general-topology, cobordism

In the category $Cob_n$ of closed $n-1$ dimensional manifolds and cobordisms between them, I am wondering what happens when we restrict our attention only to spheres. In the case when $n=2$, the only closed $1$ manifolds are disjoint unions of circles and any cobordism between any two closed $1$-manifolds can be built from pants, copants, cups and caps. Is it always true that any cobordism between two disjoint unions of spheres can be built from these elementary pieces?

Comment: A cobordism $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ is (almost) the same as just a manifold, by capping off the boundaries with discs. So you're asking whether you can build up an arbitrary manifold out of elementary pieces. Certainly not the elementary pieces you suggested. Look up "handlebody decompositions".